# Problem sub-total Matrix with rdlc report in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, matrix, rdlc, report, subtotal

I have a matrix and I need to add the money earned this year and past years. However, I must remove the money spent in past years. I must have the separate amount per year and the total of these amounts. This is what gives my matrix:

```
Year
= Fields!Year.value         =formatnumber((sum(Fields!Results.Value))-(sum(iif(
                          Fields!Year.value < Parameters!choosedYear.Value,
                          Fields!Moneyspent.value,0))), 2) & "$"
```

However, the subtotal gives me an error. What should I do?

P.S.: I already found that the subtotal gives me an error because it's not in the scope of the rowgroup1, but is there a way to get the scope in the subtotal? or can anybody find another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
=formatnumber(sum(Fields!Results.Value)-iif(
                          Fields!Year.value < Parameters!choosedYear.Value,
                          sum( Fields!Moneyspent.value), 0), 2) & "$"
```